# Using Pandas to drop rows based on 2 columns with an "AND"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to sort an clean up a spreadsheet.

Given a sheet with the column headers "Severity", "Fixable", "CVE" and "Date" I'm trying to drop all rows from "vulns_new_or_changed" if the "Severity" is "LOW" and the "Fixable" is "FALSE" and put the dropped rows into "lowAndUnfixable" I'm doing this:

```
mask = ( vulns_new_or_changed['Fixable'].isin(['FALSE']) ) & ( vulns_new_or_changed['Severity'].isin(['LOW']) )         
lowAndUnfixable = vulns_new_or_changed.drop(vulns_new_or_changed[~mask].index)
vulns_new_or_changed.drop(vulns_new_or_changed[mask].index, inplace = True)
```

Sample Data looks like this:

```
Severity, Fixable, CVE, Date
HIGH, TRUE, XXXXXX, Jan 2023
LOW, FALSE, XXXXXX, Mar 2023
LOW, TRUE, XXXXXX, MAY 2023
```

Result for lowAndUnfixable should be:

```
LOW, FALSE, XXXXXX, Mar 2023
```

I either get 0 if I DO "[~mask]" or all of them if I do "[mask]".   Any ideas?

Comment: Without the sample data, this is not reproducible and should be closed. Also, you ask for `"False"` but in your code it's `"FALSE"`, **and** Pandas might parse `False` in excel into boolean `False`. FYI, you don't have to `.drop(df[~mask].index)`, you can just do `.loc[mask]`

Comment: @Robert Put sample data and expected output in the question.  Please edit your post to include these data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your values of `Fixable` really are strings `TRUE`/`FALSE` and not bools. When reading in your data as-is, Python automatically converts these to bools.

```
mask = ( ( vulns_new_or_changed['Fixable'] == False ) & 
         ( vulns_new_or_changed['Severity'].isin(['LOW']) )
       )
vulns_new_or_changed[mask]
```

Gives exactly as expected:

```
  Severity  Fixable     CVE      Date
1      LOW    False  XXXXXX  Mar 2023
```

Comment: If I do the mask with both Fixable and Severity as you listed I get 2532 results, if I do it with just 'Fixable' ( drop the & and second part ) I get 1418, if drop the Fixable and just leave in Severity i get 2532.  I should be getting 1043 based on a manual filter of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Any possibility of hidden characters? This sounds like there's something off with the data being read in.

Comment: @StuSztukowski, [please edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the Question to include example data which produces the `1043` figure you're looking for, or some simplified setup that looks for a smaller number of result rows. As stated, we cannot tell if a proposed answer is correct, and cannot tell in which direction the code should go.

Comment: I believe you meant @Robert :)